# Find $\cos (x)$ and $\tan (x)$ if $\sin (x) = 3/5$ over the interval $[\pi/2,\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

Need help with this please. I seem to be making a mistake somewhere because my answer is different from the text book's. Mine are:

$\cos(x) = \frac{4}{5}$

$\tan(x) = \frac{3}{4}$

But in the text book it's:
$\cos(x) = \frac{-4}{5}$

$\tan(x) = \frac{-3}{4}$

I'm not sure where I went wrong.

My approach was to treat the ratio of $\sin(x)$ as the sides of a right angled triangle and solve for the final side using Pythagoras' theorem. But I don't know where the negative values are coming from. Please help if you can.

Comment: The negative values come from "over the interval $[\pi/2, \pi]$" - $\cos, \tan$ are negative there.

Comment: You build a right angled triangle with one of its angles on $[\pi/2, \pi]$ ? How exactly did you do that?

Comment: @jjagmath I didn't use the interval but the ratios.

Answer (score 1):

If $\theta\in\left(\frac\pi2,\pi\right]$, both $\cos\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ are smaller than or equal to $0$. So, you cannot possibly have $\cos\theta=\frac45$ and $\tan\theta=\frac34$ there.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the basic question, but then why are cos θ  and tan θ smaller than or equal to 0 over this particular interval? I thought so long as the interval was positive there'd be no negative values? Edit - Actually nevermind. I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

We know that

$ sin(x) ^2+cos(x)^2=1$$\Rightarrow$ $cos(x) =\sqrt{1-sin(x)^2} $or $- \sqrt{1-sin(x)^2}$

So

$cos(x) =\frac{4}{5}$ or $- \frac{4}{5}$

We know that $x\in [\pi, \frac{\pi} {2}]$ $\Rightarrow$$ cos(x) =<0 $

so $cos(x) =- \frac{4}{5}$

$Tan(x) =-\frac{3}{4}$